# Convergence Notation: $L^k$ and $L^k(dQ)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

What is the difference between the following convergence notations: $L^k$ and $L^k(dQ)$?

I am familiar with typical $L^n$-convergence, but what does $dQ$ represent?

Comment: I suspect $dQ$ is the measure underlying the integral that defines the $L^k$-space, but you didn't explain that.  For a measure $\mu$ on a set $X$, the Wikipedia page on $L^p$-spaces writes $L^p(X,\mu)$ for the $L^p$-functions $X \to \mathbf C$.  I've seen $L^p(\mu)$ also.

Comment: $f_i \to f$ in $L^{k} (dQ)$ if $\int |f_i-f|^{k} dQ \to 0$. $Q$ is a measure.

Comment: If we only write $L^k$, the measure is usually clear from context

Comment: Thanks guys, @KaviRamaMurthy, Thanks Kavi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could give a little more of context (book, exercise?) but it comes to my mind is that $dQ$ is a measure then $f_i \to f$in $L^k(dQ)$ is equivalent to $\left(\int|f_i-f|^kdQ\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}\to 0$.